# Can someone explain the formal grammar behind this phrase: "glad shall he be"?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

What is the formal grammar behind the phrase "*glad shall he be*"?

I think the "he be" portion indicates subjunctive tense but I am not sure. Also, why is there "shall" instead of "will"? I thought "shall" is preferred with "I/we".

An explanation of we/shall and/or the subjunctive conjugation in English would be appreciated with the explanation.

Comment: This is an archaic way of writing "he shall be glad". Inverting the order doesn't change the tense or mood.

Comment: could you please elaborate on the difference between archaic order vs modern order?

Comment: Also it is subjunctive right? (he be glad vs he is glad?)

Comment: This order is generally only found in old writing, like the King James Bible. If you see it in modern writing, it's an intentional style choice to sound flowery or poetic.

Comment: "he be glad" is subjunctive, it has to be part of a larger phrase, like "I suggested he be glad".

Comment: @Barmar: (This may be what you're saying, but just to be clear:) It's true that "he be glad" can be subjunctive, but it isn't here - the "be" is just the bare infinitive that always appears after "shall" ("he shall be"); it just looks confusing because the "shall" is no longer next to the "be".

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. "glad he shall be" is not the same as "he be glad". They're not related at all.

Comment: "Glad shall he be" is an example of [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(linguistics)). It might be done to emphasise "glad". Although there are other reasons for inversion, such as in poetry for rhyme or meter, or in song to fit the melody, stress, and rhythm. You'd need to look at where you found that expression.

Comment: It's Yoda-ish..

Comment: For the difference between *shall* and *will* see https://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/shall_will.htm

Comment: Answered at [inversion ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/391250/inversion-with-a-prepositional-phrase/391256#391256) (subject-complement inversion).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not to mention [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/589613/2085), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78595/2085), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/558372/2085), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/71346/2085), [5](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/430506/2085), [6](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/570353/2085), [7](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/96624/2085), [8](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/527396/2085).

Comment: Here in the waning minutes of Coronation Day (in New York time), I can’t refrain from offering this sentence for comparison, “Uneasy is the head that wears a crown.”—Shakespeare, *Henry IV, Part Two*

Answer (score 4):

> "glad shall he be"

This is an archaic use of the guidance that the verb should be the second element in a sentence. Thus fronting adverbs/adjectives were the first element and caused an apparent subject verb inversion:

e.g. "**Long** was the road to her heart but **dearly** did I love her."

Outside poetic/literary language, this now exists only in a few adverbial locative cases and usually in "to be" clauses:

Here (adv.) are (v.) your gloves (subj.), and there (adv.) is (v.) your hat (subj.)

"In the garden was a cat."

Just to reiterate: there is no subjunctive in "Glad shall he be." - you should have recogised the modal "shall" ... modals are followed by a bare infinitive.